# If $y=(e)^{x^x}$, then find the value of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=(e)^{x^x}$, then find the value of $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}.$

I have got the right answer but the answer given on the solution page is $y'=(e)^{x^x}\cdot{x^x}\cdot(1+\operatorname{log (\mathrm{x}))}.$

I have tried a lot but I am not able to arrive on this answer.

Comment: Tried what exactly? If you tell us what you’ve tried, we can tell you where you’re going wrong.

Comment: ok wait a min let me write my work

Comment: You need to post your answer and how you got it and why you think it the "right answer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, take the natural log of both sides of the equation.
$$\ln(y) = x^x \ln(e) = x^x.$$
Now, differentiate both sides wrt $x$.
$$\frac{y'}{y} = \frac{d}{dx}(x^x).$$

Now, introduce another function $z(x) = x^x$ and find $z'$ separately, again using natural log trick.
$$\ln(z) = x\ln(x).$$
$$\frac{z'}{z} = \ln(x)+1 \implies z' = z(1+\ln(x)) = x^x(1+\ln(x)).$$
Therefore,
$$y' = yz' = e^{x^x}x^x(1+\ln(x)).$$

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to rewrite $y$ into a composition of functions and use the chain rule. Namely, rewrite
$$y(x)=e^{x^x}=e^{e^{\log(x^x)}}=e^{e^{x\log x}}=f(f(g(x))$$
where $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=x\log x$. Then calculate $f'(x)=e^x$ and $g'(x)=1+\log x$. We can now use the chain rule to find $y'$, that is,
$$y'(x)=f'(f(g(x)))\cdot f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)=e^{f(g(x))}\cdot e^{g(x)}\cdot(1+\log x)=e^{x^x}\cdot x^x\cdot(1+\log x).$$

Comment: how is $x^x=e^{x\operatorname{log x}}$?

Comment: @Zootopia Using the property $a^{\log_a(b)} = b$

Comment: Because e^[ln(x)]=x, for all non-zero positive x.